# Viewing a small region of a Large Image in Android

Tags: android, graphics, memory-limit

In a gist this is what I want to do:

***I want to load a 100x100 region (any part) of a 5mega pixel Image into a Android Bitmap class so that I can draw it onto a canvas element***
Its that simple. Thats all I want to do. Thats it. Nothing more. Nothing less. Sounds simple enough. So before you have a smirk on your face, read on further down.

I understand that this question has been asked a million times already. And I have also done my homework, researching it. Unfortunately I have hit a dead end from all sides. Maybe I need to make my question clear enough.

There is a limit on the amount of heap the Android VM lets you allocate. So loading a large bitmap, even the one from its own camera (I own a Nexus S) is not possible by using the following function.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(InputStream is)
```

Yes I could scale it by using **BitmapFactory.Options**, but how then should I zoom in?

Now I am trying to design an image viewer which can smoothly zoom in/out from the image. Obviously that's not possible if I can't even load the image.

In gingerbread we have a new class **BitmapRegionDecoder** , but I am designing my app for Froyo. All these classes have hooks into the native api which use the **Skia 2D Graphics Library**. The Android NDK does not give access to these api's also. Maybe there is a way to manually build Skia and use it to load a java bitmap. But I am not sure how?

It seems to have been solved already (http://blog.javia.org/how-to-work-around-androids-24-mb-memory-limit/) in this app - https://market.android.com/details?id=image.viewer by using the memory allocated in the native C code using **malloc/new**. But I cant figure out how?

So make things clearer what I want is something that can zoom in/out of an image to full resolution. If possible it should be smooth or atleast it can be done in a separate thread.

If I need to use OpenGL, then please give me a sample code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. :)

Its not the best way, but it works wonderfully.

I created the bitmap in native code and accessed subset of its region using the Skia graphics library. (Which would mean that I am accessing private API's and its functionality could easily break with newer Android Versions).

http://code.google.com/p/skia/

I had to link against this lib in my C++ code and access this functionality through JNI.